# Python inheritance Best way to merge info with parents

Tags: python, inheritance, class-attributes

Imagine we have a class Animal with a class attribute `info`, which is a dictionary. There is a class Frog which inherits from Animal and also has a class attribute `info`. But the attribute `info` of the Frog class must also include the Animal info.

```
class Animal:
    info = {'one':1, 'two':2}

class Frog(Animal):
    info = {'three':3}

assert 'three' in Frog.info
```

I can use @property

```
class Frog(Animal):
    _info = {'three':3}
    @property
    def info(self):
         return self._info | Frog.info
```

But this is just fragile. Do the large Python library includes any Class that doesn't overwrite the Class attributes?

Comment: Why use a single dictionary instead of individual attributes `one`, `two`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `info` values to be automatically merged by subclasses, you will need to use a metaclass to achieve this.

The metaclass is code which can modify the class *definition*, so it can look at the value of `info` on the parent class and the value of `info` in the sub-class as it is being defined ... and it can merge them and set the result of that as the value of `info` in the resulting sub-class.

It would look like this:

```py
class MergeInfoMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
        base_info = {}
        for base in bases:
            try:
                base_info.update(base.info)
            except AttributeError:
                continue

        try:
            info = attrs["info"]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            attrs["info"] = base_info | info
        
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)


class Animal(metaclass=MergeInfoMetaclass):
    info = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}


class Frog(Animal):
    info = {'three': 3}


class GoldenTreeFrog(Frog):
    info = {'four': 4}


assert Animal.info == {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

assert Frog.info == {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}

assert GoldenTreeFrog.info == {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
```

You can find more info about Python metaclasses here https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/#custom-metaclasses

Basically, when Python is reading your class definition, like:

```py
class Animal(metaclass=MergeInfoMetaclass):
    info = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

Python takes the details of the new class (the name, base classes and class attrs, which include the methods too) and passes them to the metaclass. At this point the `Animal` class does not exist yet. The metaclass is responsible for creating the new class object (meaning the class itself and not an instance of the class).

Comment: What if multiple of the base classes have `info`? `base_info.update(base.info)` is probably better right? Also why not use `hasattr` instead of try-except?

Comment: I agree on the first point, will update the answer. Try/except is generally more idiomatic in Python https://realpython.com/python-lbyl-vs-eafp https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/

Comment: Thank you very much @Anentropic. I knew the existence of metaclasses but my knowledge is far from knowing how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the parent's attribute in the child.

```
class Frog(Animal):
    info = Animal.info + {'three': 3}
```